# How to write a join query for mongoDb with Spring boot?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

everyone!
I would be very grateful for your help, I am a beginner in working with MongoDB.
I have 2 classes

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Document(collection = "user")
public class User {
    @Transient
    public static final String USER_SEQUENCE = "user_sequence";
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
    @DBRef
    private List<Article> articles = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Document(collection = "articles")
public class Article {
    @Transient
    public static final String ARTICLE_SEQUENCE = "article_sequence";
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String text;
    private int like = 0;
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private Set<Long> likedBy = new HashSet<>();
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private Set<Long> dislikedBy = new HashSet<>();
    @DBRef
    private User user;

    public Article(Long id, String text, User user) {
        this.id = id;
        this.text = text;
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

I need to implement a method that will retrieve all articles by username
This is my implementation, but it doesn't work(((

```
public interface ArticleRepository extends MongoRepository<Article, Long> {
    List<Article> findAllByOrderByIdDesc();

    @Aggregation(pipeline = {
            "{$lookup: {from: 'users', localField: 'user', foreignField: '_id', as: 'user'}}",
            "{$unwind: '$user'}",
            "{$match: {'user.username': ?0}}"
    })
    List<Article> findAllByUserUsername(String username);
}
```

Help me understand how to do this, please

Of course, I can pull out the User by name and take the gender from it, but I think it's not right.

```
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, Long> {
    Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);
}
```

Comment: You can remove the `@DBRef articles` from User class.  I believe it will form an endless loop if you DBRef two classes into one another.

Also, please share the exact error that you are getting in your implementation.

Comment: error - Invalid path reference user.username! Associations can only be pointed to directly or via their id property!

Answer (score 0):

On `$lookup` stage you're trying to join on `user` field which is a DBRef in the articles collection and `_id` field in the users collection. The issue is that DBRef is a complex object, and you cannot directly compare it with the `_id` field.

In MongoDB, a DBRef is a document that contains the following fields:

```
{
   $ref : <collection name>,
   $id : <id>,
   $db : <database name>
}
```

Your `User` field in the `Article` collection would look something like this:

```
{
    $ref : 'user',
    $id : <user_id>,
    $db : <database_name>
}
```

Thus, in your `$lookup` part, you should use `user.$id` as the localField instead of `user`:

```
@Aggregation(pipeline = {
        "{$lookup: {from: 'user', localField: 'user.$id', foreignField: '_id', as: 'user'}}",
        "{$unwind: '$user'}",
        "{$match: {'user.username': ?0}}"
})
List<Article> findAllByUserUsername(String username);
```

Comment: I still get Invalid path reference user.username! Associations can only be pointed to directly or via their id property!

Comment: Maybe try, instead of using `$lookup` operation, to reference related data by ID directly in your documents, and then perform separate queries to retrieve the related data

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch only the list of articles from the User repository as follows:

Keep your User class as is in your question.

Remove `@DBRef private User user;` from your Article class.

`User Repository`

```
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query("select u.articles from User u where u.username:=username")
    List<Article> findArticlesbyUsername(@Param("username") String username);
}
```

This will fetch only the list of articles through your User class.

Answer (score 0):

I took the idea from the Dhaval Simaria solution, but I tweaked it a bit, and now it works.

```
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, Long> {
    Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);

    @Aggregation(pipeline = {
            "{$match: {username: ?0}}",
            "{$lookup: {from: 'articles', localField: 'id', foreignField: 'user.id', as: 'articles'}}",
            "{$unwind: '$articles'}",
            "{$replaceRoot: {newRoot: '$articles'}}"
    })
    List<Article> findArticlesByUsername(String username);
}
```

It is very important for me to know if it is the right decision to write this method in UserRepository or is it better to look for options to do it in ArticleRepository?

Comment: Going by the structure of your User class and Article class and assuming you removed `@DBRef` in one place, this solution looks good. But a lot depends on your functional requirement in order to properly decide whether to place User class object within Article class or vice-versa.